# Where can I find CPU voltage on android device?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, cpu, power-management

I'm trying to write an app that tells me what the voltage of my CPU is, but I cannot find the needed information.  I've tried /proc/stat, top, and more, but I am starting to feel lost.  Currently, I'm searching through /sys/kernel/debug, and I've found some things in there, but I don't always know what they are.  For instance /mmc0/ios gives me a voltage value, but I don't think it is my CPU (or is it?).  If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be sweet!

Thanks

Comment: If this is available on a given device (which in many cases, it probably is not) there would be evidence of that fact in the device-specific parts of the kernel sources.

Comment: So it would be somewhere in /sys/devices ?

Comment: Running thorugh the HWMONs, which I just found out about, hoping to find something there!

Comment: @Kmanc There are a number of voltage regulators in Android devices.  For MSM platform, try looking here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-msm/vreg.c